# Add XML layout and removing another programmitacially

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a Fragment and partial code from my app is:

```
mFrame3 =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( R.layout.ptrip, container, false ); //display if file exist
noFilesDisplayed = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nofile, container, false); //display if file doesn't exist

if (FilesInFolder != null) { //function to check if any file exist
    mFrame3.findViewById(R.layout.ptrip).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //display this layout
    noFilesDisplayed.findViewById(R.layout.nofile).setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide this layout
}
else {
    mFrame3.findViewById(R.layout.ptrip).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    noFilesDisplayed.findViewById(R.layout.nofile).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I am not sure if it's the best way but what I am looking to do is if there are any files in the directory to show the `mFrame3` RelativeLayout XML file and hide `noFilesDisplayed` otherwise show the `noFilesDisplayed` RelativeLayout XML file and hide `mFrame3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show/hide the whole "mFrame3" or "noFilesDisplayed" views, you could simply call mFrame3.setVisibility() and noFilesDisplayed.setVisibility()...

Comment: Right now with my code, my app is FC. Will your edit resolve it?

Comment: I also had to add the return statement for the correct Layout and it's working fine :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening once per fragment life cycle just do it in the [`onCreateView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) function, and don't inflate both, the visible and invisible layout.